# GCE create multiple VMs at once

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I create multiple VMs via node.js API in the same zone from the same image. The API response seems fine. But I can only see 2 VMs in the google cloud console. Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

```
 // this is called multiple times with different vmNames:
 const Compute = require('@google-cloud/compute');
 const compute = new Compute();
 const zone = compute.zone('us-central1-a');
 await zone.createVM(vmName, config).then(async (data) => {
            const vm = data[0];
            const operation = data[1];
            const apiResponse = data[2];

            var vmid = data[2].id;
            console.log('created vm ' + vmid); // is called multiple times, but in reality only 2 VMs are created

});
```

Seems that I exceed my quota.

`quotaExceeded "IN_USE_ADDRESSES" limit 8`

But why and what can I do?

Comment: Hi there! You need to request extra quota. Take a look to [Running out of quota](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#running_out) section from [Working with quotas](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#running_out) page. You exceeded your IP addresses quota so your only options are creating VMS under different regions (like some un us-central and other in us-west) but you will hit the GLOBAL quota. So, your only real solution is to ask for more quota.

Comment: If you can not request quota since you are in free trial, my advice is to leverage the need of external IPs. Maybe you can use Cloud NAT so you can reduce the number of External IPs.

Comment: @ArmandoCuevas Thanks. I will look into that NAT thing. I don't really need any IP. But I hope firebase/firestore works with that

Comment: seems to work with the cloud console, but I struggle with the node api to not set the external ip https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69488409/gce-node-api-use-custom-network-with-no-external-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated before, you might need to request a quota increase for your Google Project.

Also, here is the information regarding [quota increase](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/quota) and external IP addresses.

In-use external IP addresses include both ephemeral and static IP addresses that are currently being used by a resource.

If the same IP address is assigned to more than one forwarding rule, Google Cloud counts and adds each usage of the address towards the [IN_USE_ADDRESSES](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#external_ip_addresses) quota rather than a unique count of IP address objects that are used.

Here is a detailed [guide](http://www.queryadmin.com/2141/quota-in_use_addresses-exceeded-limit-8-0-in-region/) on how to request a quota increase for the IP’s