# GCE Node Api use custom network with no external IP

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I struggle with creating a new vm via the node google compute engine API. The cloud console gives me the REST code when no external IP is selected:

```
 "networkInterfaces": [
    {
      "subnetwork": "projects/optum-80593/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/subnet-us-central1"
    }
  ]
```

But when I use this in my config for the node API, the external IP is still set to that VM:

```
 const Compute = require('@google-cloud/compute');
 const compute = new Compute();
 const zone = compute.zone('us-central1-a');

 const config = {
        machineType: machinetype,
        maintenancePolicy: 'MIGRATE',
        http: true,
        disks: [
          ...
        ],
        canIpForward: false,
        networkInterfaces: [
            {
                subnetwork: "projects/optum-80593/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/subnet-us-central1"
            }
        ], 
   ...
}

await zone.createVM(vmName, config).then(async (data) => {
```

Comment: There is currently no method to set the VM external IP to none when it is created using node js. Instead, you can remove the external IP using the `deleteAccessConfig` [API call](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/deleteAccessConfig) from your NodeJS code once the machine is established.

Comment: After the VM is established, you can make a call to the API using your preferred NodeJS library. Set the "accessConfig" parameter to "external-nat" and the "networkInterface" parameter to "nic0." The other arguments match the details of the VM from which you're attempting to remove the external IP.

Comment: Actually it is possible, you just have to omit the `accessConfigs` and you'll have a VM without external IP. I tested at my end the way you're doing and I got a VM without external IP. Maybe there is something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, when I copy the whole REST code to my node API.